# How make an animation work on a specific page in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the below HTML and CSS for a contact page animation:

```css
page-id-1239 {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align- items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact {
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact::before .contact::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contact::before {
  left: 2px;
  clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  background: #000;
  animation: brasil-anim-2 1s infinite linear alternate- reverse;
}

.contact:after {
  left: -2px;
  clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  text-shadow: -1px 0 blue 000;
  animation: brasil-anim-1 1s infinite linear alternate- reverse;
  Animation-delay: -1s;
}

@keyframes brasil-anim-1 {
  0% {
    Clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 76px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    Clip: rect(19px, 1200px, 16px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    Clip: rect(16px, 1200px, 3px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    Clip: rect(62px, 1200px, 78px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    Clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 13px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    Clip: rect(53px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes brasil-anim-2 {
  0% {
    Clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    Clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 30px, 0)
  }
  40% {
    Clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 5px, 0)
  }
  60% {
    Clip: rect(65px, 1200px, 85px
  }
  80% {
    Clip: rect(120px, 1200px, 145px, 0)
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(95px, 1200px, 75px, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact" data
text="CONTACT">CONTACT</div>
```

This should produce an animation in which the word `contact` flickers like a faulty tv set. The background should be white and text black with a sort of bar or screen that moves up and down the word to hide and reveal it.

Problem 1: It doesn't work, why?

Problem 2: When I start with `body` it messes my whole site up. When I start from `page-id-1239` it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

After looking at your site, add the following line:

```css
.contact {
  …
  line-height: 2;
}
```

---

**Problem 1: It doesn't work, why?**

There was an issue in how you called the animation.

- improper shorthand property `alternate- reverse`. You must remove the space between the dash and the 'r' of 'reverse'

There were a few other typos as well, but nothing that prevented the animation from working.

```css
.page-id-1239 {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact {
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact::before,
.contact::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contact::before {
  left: 2px;
  clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  background: #000;
  animation: brasil-anim-2 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

.contact:after {
  left: -2px;
  clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  text-shadow: -1px 0 blue 000;
  animation: brasil-anim-1 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

@keyframes brasil-anim-1 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 76px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(19px, 1200px, 16px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(16px, 1200px, 3px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(62px, 1200px, 78px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 13px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(53px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes brasil-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 30px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 5px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(65px, 1200px, 85px);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(120px, 1200px, 145px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(95px, 1200px, 75px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact" data-text="CONTACT">CONTACT</div>
```

**Problem 2: When I start with body it messes my whole site up. When I start from page-id-1239 it doesn't do anything.**

What you've included is not a valid `CSS` selector. You need to prefix it with either a dot `.` or pound sign `#` to denote a `class` or `id`, respectively.

```css
page-id-1239 { … }
```